# Show text when hovering over an element in a dynamic search

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have this code snipped which executes a dynamic search.

```
<f:facet name="right" >
    <p:autoComplete id="searchTree"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    autoHighlight="true"
                    minQueryLength="2"
                    scrollHeight="700"
                    value="#{treeSelectionView.configItemDtoSearchSelected}"
                    completeMethod="#{treeSelectionView.searchAllNodes}"
                    var="configItemDtoSearch"
                    itemValue="#{configItemDtoSearch}"
                    itemLabel="#{configItemDtoSearch.name}"
                    effect="fade"
                    converter="#{treeSearchConverter}">

        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{depedencyView.onNodeSearchSelect}"
                update="configItemForm:configItemTree configItemForm:toolBar  :centerContentPanel :dependencyPanel"
                oncomplete="focusOnSelectedTree()" />
    </p:autoComplete>
</f:facet>
```

I have another property `configItemDtoSearch.fullPath`. I want to show that property when hovering over an item (identified by `configItemDtoSearch.name`) in the search results. Is there a build in functionality in primefaces for this ? How can I do that ?

PS: There seem to be such functionality using `tooltip`, but I have no idea how to combine them. It can probably be done using JavaScript as well. The problem is getting the `var="configItemDtoSearch"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `Itemtip` example on `primeFaces`

```
<p:outputLabel value="Itemtip:" for="itemTip" />
        <p:autoComplete id="itemTip" value="#{autoCompleteView.theme3}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeTheme}"
                        var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme.displayName}" itemValue="#{theme}" converter="themeConverter" forceSelection="true">
            <f:facet name="itemtip">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-theme ui-theme-#{theme.name}" style="margin-left:50px" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="Display:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{theme.displayName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Key" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{theme.name}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>
</p:autoComplete>
```